# Como posso definir a ordem de listagem na biblioteca list.js

Tags: javascript

Estou usando essa biblioteca para filtro de dados em buscas, até ai tudo bem, mas eu preciso clicar um select para a pessoa escolher se deseja definir a ordem da listagem de forma acrescente ou decrescente, alguém sabe como proceder? a lib é essa: https://github.com/jiren/filter.js/tree/master

Comment: Essa biblioteca não faz ordenação mas pode usar o evento before render para ordenar os registos

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de usar esse evento junto da biblioteca? no caso é possível usar com o select para a pessoa poder escolher?

Comment: Se vc puder me orientar eu agradeço muito, eu até pagaria mas estou sem dinheiro

Comment: Aqui não usamos dinheiro se quiser pode sempre oferecer uma recompensa em pontos

Comment: Vai ter que postar  um exemplo funcional ainda que simplificado do que precisa

Comment: Eu usei o próprio site da demo e usei o inspecionar elemento pra tentar explicar melhor o que quero https://imgur.com/X1Ws0nO

Comment: tem como dar meus pontos todos? caso tenha, eu te dou eles todos, não to sabendo mais o que fazer pra resolver esse probleminha

Comment: essa ordenação eu iria fazer através do id contido no arquivo json